# NodeJS - Mysql Error while insert data to database

Tags: mysql, node.js

I got a function like getItemPrice in nodeJS. But while trying to inserting datas there is a error occuring. Can't write any dynamic value inside VALUES(item.Id, value.lowest_price).

I've tried lots of things bot none of work.

```
con.query('SELECT game_item.id as itemId, steam_app_game.app_id as gameId, game_item.name, steam_app_game.id FROM steam_app_game LEFT JOIN game_item ON steam_app_game.id = game_item.app_game_id', function(err, rows, fields) {
var counter = 1;
rows.forEach(function (item,index) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            market.getItemPrice(item.gameId, item.name).then(function (value, err) {
                if(err) throw  err;
                var lowest = value.lowest_price
                con.query('INSERT INTO game_item_spec(game_item_id,price) VALUES (item.itemId,value.lowest_price )')
                counter ++;
            });
        }, index * 5000);
    });
});
```

Here is the error.

```
ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'value.lowest_price' in 'field list'
at Query.Sequence._packetToError (F:\Xamp\htdocs\steam-trade-bot\node_modules\mysql\lib\protocol\sequences\Sequence.js:47
:14)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this using parameter statements in nodeJs. Single insert into doesn’t work for if the data has special chars

Answer (score 0):

A query must be a string, so to inject some variables inside you can use ES6 syntax with template string. 
Here the working code:

```
con.query('SELECT game_item.id as itemId, steam_app_game.app_id as gameId, game_item.name, steam_app_game.id FROM steam_app_game LEFT JOIN game_item ON steam_app_game.id = game_item.app_game_id', function(err, rows, fields) {
var counter = 1;
rows.forEach(function (item,index) {
        setTimeout(function(){
            market.getItemPrice(item.gameId, item.name).then(function (value, err) {
                if(err) throw  err;
                var lowest = value.lowest_price
                con.query(`INSERT INTO game_item_spec(game_item_id,price) VALUES (${item.itemId}, ${value.lowest_price} )`)
                counter ++;
            });
        }, index * 5000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend that you use node async https://caolan.github.io/async/, use [series](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#series) together with [eachOfSeries](https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachOfSeries)